# How can I change the constraints so that it was like on the second screenshot?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

Please can you help me to change constraints in code to take an elements like in the second screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKve8.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXBfr.png)

```
class DetailsHomeViewController: UIViewController {

var images:[String] = ["label","label","label"]

let MainImageView: UIImageView = {
          let theImageView = UIImageView()
          theImageView.image = UIImage(named: "label.png")
          theImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
          return theImageView
       }()

let someImageView: UIImageView = {
    let theImageView = UIImageView()
    theImageView.backgroundColor = .white
    theImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    theImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return theImageView
}()

lazy var collectionView:UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.register(ImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: ImageCell.identifier)
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return cv
}()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(MainImageView)
    view.addSubview(someImageView)
    someImageView.addSubview(collectionView)
    someImageViewConstraints()
    MainImageViewConstraints()
    
    view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    setupViews()
    mysetupViews()
}


private func setupViews() {
    someImageViewConstraints()
}


func someImageViewConstraints() {
    someImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.width/2)
    someImageView.center = view.center

    let itemHeight = 120
    let padding = 25
    let width = (itemHeight * 3) + padding
    collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: Int(view.center.x) - (width / 2),
                                  y: Int(someImageView.frame.height) - (itemHeight + padding),
                                  width: width, height: itemHeight)
  
}

private func mysetupViews() {
        createCustomNavigationBar()
        
        let RightButton = createCustomButton(
            imageName: "square.and.arrow.up",
            selector: #selector(RightButtonTapped)
        )
        
        let customTitleView = createCustomTitleView(
            detailsName: "Label"
        )
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [RightButton]
        navigationItem.titleView = customTitleView
    }

@objc private func RightButtonTapped() {
    print("RightButtonTapped")
}



func MainImageViewConstraints() {
    MainImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
           
        } }
```

extension DetailsHomeViewController:UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegate {

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ImageCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
    cell.someImageView.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

} extension DetailsHomeViewController:UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.height, height: collectionView.frame.height)
}
```

}

```
class ImageCell:UICollectionViewCell {
static let identifier = "ImageCell"

 
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        self.someImageView.layer.borderColor = isSelected ? UIColor.green.cgColor : UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.someImageView.layer.borderWidth = 5
    }
}

let someImageView: UIImageView = {
    let theImageView = UIImageView()
    theImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    return theImageView
}()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    addSubview(someImageView)
    someImageView.frame = self.bounds
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    //someImageView.frame = self.frame
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Comment: First, you should be using auto-layout constraints, not explicit frames. Second, is your intent to have a horizontal-scrolling collection view (with variable number of small images) below the main view? Or, are you only going to have 3 small image views there?

Comment: i am going to have 1 big images and then 3 small images lower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to go through a bunch of good auto-layout tutorials, but here is a quick general idea...

[image]

We'll constrain the "main image view" 12-points from the top, 40-points from each side, and give it a 5:3 ratio.

Then we'll add a `UIStackView` (with 12-point spacing) below it, constrained 12-points from the bottom of the main image view, 75% of the width, centered horizontally.

Each image view that we add to the stack view will be constrained to a 1:2 ratio (square).

Here's sample code to do that:

```
class DetailsHomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var images:[String] = ["label", "label", "label"]
    
    let mainImageView: UIImageView = {
        let theImageView = UIImageView()
        theImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        theImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        theImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 24.0
        return theImageView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

        setupViews()

        mysetupViews()
    }
    
    
    private func setupViews() {
        
        // a stack view to hold the "thumbnail" image views
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.spacing = 12
        
        mainImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(mainImageView)
        view.addSubview(stackView)

        // respect the safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // main image view - let's go with
            //  Top with 12-points "padding"
            mainImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            //  Leading and Trailing with 40-points "padding"
            mainImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            mainImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            // height equal to width x 3/5ths (5:3 aspect ratio)
            mainImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 3.0 / 5.0),

            // stack view
            //  Top 12-points from main image view Bottom
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            //  width equal to 75% of the main image view width
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
            //  centered horizontally
            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainImageView.centerXAnchor),

        ])

        // make sure we can load the main image
        if let img = UIImage(named: images[0]) {
            mainImageView.image = img
        }

        // now we'll add 3 image views to the stack view
        images.forEach { imgName in
            let thumbView = UIImageView()
            thumbView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            thumbView.clipsToBounds = true
            thumbView.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
            // we want them to be square
            thumbView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thumbView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            // make sure we can load the image
            if let img = UIImage(named: imgName) {
                thumbView.image = img
            }
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(thumbView)
        }
        
    }
    
    private func mysetupViews() {
        createCustomNavigationBar()
        
        let RightButton = createCustomButton(
            imageName: "square.and.arrow.up",
            selector: #selector(RightButtonTapped)
        )
        
        let customTitleView = createCustomTitleView(
            detailsName: "Label"
        )
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [RightButton]
        navigationItem.titleView = customTitleView
    }
    
    @objc private func RightButtonTapped() {
        print("RightButtonTapped")
    }
    
}
```